# Editing MediaWiki metadata

Tags: mediawiki

I'm going to set up a MediaWiki instance that needs to support user-generated page metadata. These metadata entries are name-value pairs. The names and values are specified by the page authors.

[`Extension:MetaData`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Metadata) seems to provide the necessary infrastructure. It also seems pretty straightforward to implement a template that displays the metadata.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to actually let the editors edit the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

[Managing data in MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Managing_data_in_MediaWiki) lists the common approaches (which might be a bit of an overkill, depending on what you are trying to do).

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look to [semantic mediawiki extensions](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki) ?